# How to work with locally modified Cocoapod which don't include podspec?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

What is the best way to locally use and modify Cocoapods?

In my case, I'd like to extend a pod, ReactiveCocoa, by another method. Also, I want to work from the pod's Git repository so that I can create a branch or patch.

For libraries that have a podspec in their base directory, this is easily accomplished with the `:path` option. With other pods that have a third-party podspec I didn't see an obvious way to do that. (The developers of ReactiveCocoa don't provide a podspec themselves.) Is there a good solution?

There is a `:podspec` option for pods, too. But that doesn't seem to work together with the :path option, as changes to the sources at the references path aren't picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically fork the repo, add the podspec and then make changes, here is [an example](https://github.com/artsy/eidolon/blob/master/Podfile#L63).

It looks like:
`pod 'ReactiveCocoa', :git => "https://github.com/ashfurrow/ReactiveCocoa", :branch => "podspec"`

Comment: Is there a good way to find the canonical podspec in DSL format? The Spec repository only contains the JSON (derived) format now, iirc. (Or are they interchangable here?)

Comment: JSON / Ruby are basically interchangeable, it's just RAC is pretty special in all these cases due to the author not wanting to have a Podspec.